# Angular 8 map data in route resolver

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx

In my route resolver I am trying to map- then return a value in my state, but I'm not sure how to approach it, or if it's a best practice.

Essentially, I want to guarantee that my route data has been mapped before I load my component. So I am mapping in my:

**Selection-Resolver.ts**

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class SelectionResolverService implements Resolve<MenuItem> {
    constructor(
        private store: Store<fromApp.AppState>, private actions$: Actions) { }

    // select our state, and map the response to the selected category/item
    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        const category = route.url[0].path;
        const selectionId = route.url[1].path;
        return this.store.select('restaurant')
            .pipe(
                take(1),
                map(restaurantState => restaurantState.restaurant.groupedMenu[category]
                    .find(selection => selection._id === selectionId)
                )
            );
    }
}
```

But, whenever I receive the value in my SelectionComponent from this route resolver, it is undefined. I assume this is because I'm not subscribing after the pipe, but I'm not sure if subscribing in a Resolver is the correct solution.

**Selection.component.ts**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe((d) => {
      console.log('data', d); // d is undefined :(
    });
```

How can I return my mapped state data to my SelectionComponent? Or should I be handling this in the component, instead.

note: The data from the store will always be defined

Comment: Where is the ```data``` in this.route.data come from ?

Comment: from the selection resolver, for example if I return 'hi' from selection-resolver.ts, it does log 'hi' ion my selection.component.ts

Comment: Please check if your store is filled with restaurantState using ngrx dev tools. Looks like your restaurantState is not having any data OR it has data but .find query returns an undefined.